# ModuleNotFoundError when running docker img of FastAPI

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, fastapi

Can anyone see what im doing wrong here? works fine locally, but when running it in docker it cant seem to find my modules ...

The **init**.py files are emtpy if that info could help. Im no expert in docker and non of the tips I've googled/stackoverflowed so far has panned out, such as adding pythonpath env in the dockerfile.

Error log from docker:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/uvicorn", line 8, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
rv = self.invoke(ctx)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
return callback(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 331, in main
run(**kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 354, in run
server.run()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 382, in run
loop.run_until_complete(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 1456, in uvloop.loop.Loop.run_until_complete
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 389, in serve
config.load()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/config.py", line 288, in load
self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 23, in import_from_string
raise exc from None
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 20, in import_from_string
module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "./main.py", line 3, in <module>
from routers.user import router as user_router
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'routers'
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.7

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends

# install requirements
RUN pip3 install fastapi[all] uvicorn[standard]

# Move files
COPY ./* /app

# attemt to fix a python ModuleNotFoundError
WORKDIR /app
#ENV PATH=$PATH:/app
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/app"

CMD [ "uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "15400"]
```

Docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services: 
    core_api:
        build: .
        container_name: "core-api-container"
        ports:
            - "8000:15400"
        volumes: 
            - ./app/:/app
```

file structure:

```
API/
--__init__.py
--Dockerfile
--docker-compose.yml
--main.py
--routers/
  --__init__.py
  --user.py
  --x.py
```

main.py:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

from routers.user import router as user_router
from routers.x import router as x_router

app = FastAPI()

app.include_router(user_router)
app.include_router(x_router)
```

Answer (score 1):

After running `docker container run -it your-docker-container bash` and checked the files, it seems docker does not copy the file hierarchy as i expected. all files was under the same folder /app. none of my subfolder from the project in my local files were added, just the files those contained. No wonder i got ModuleNotFoundError.

To fix this i simply made a new project and put all my python files in the same directoy, and edited them all to import correctly. There is probably a simpler way to fix this, but cba. to figure that out at this time.

Comment: Try using `COPY . /app`

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same issue with this and I try to fix it not by changing the directory structure of my application or how I copy the files but by running the application directly using gunicorn.

I run it with the following command :

`gunicorn -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker run:app`

that can either be updated in the entrypoint of your docker file or in the command section of compose if you are using docker-compose.

Comment: what was the initial structure and how did you change it?